# Retrieve data after deleting mapping in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am fairly new to elastic search. Just this weekend I started trying out stuff in it, and while I think it's a pretty neat way to store documents, I came across the following problem. I was fooling around a bit with the mappings (without actually knowing at the time what they were and what they were for), and I accidentally deleted the mapping of my index, along with all the data stored by performing a

```
DELETE tst_environment/object/_mapping 
{
   "properties" : {
   "title" : { "type": "string" }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve the lost data or am I, well .. fucked? Any information regarding the issue is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have taken a [snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#modules-snapshots) of the index it is not possbile to retrieve the data once you deleted the mapping. 
You would have to reindex the data from initial source

FWIW the upcoming  V2.0 of elasticsearch does not allow one to [delete mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_mapping_changes.html#_types_may_no_longer_be_deleted) .

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like there might be a snapshot of the data available. I'll have to look further into it.
Also glad to hear that this functionality will not be available in the new elasticsearch version. Being able to delete all of your data with just a simple delete request doesn't seem like a foolproof way to do things.